# How to propagate client IP address from client between multiple proxies and backends

Tags: proxy, http-headers, http-proxy

Here is the scenario that I have:

```
Client -> A SPA application -> a Proxy -> a Backend for SPA -> Service proxy -> Service Backend.
```

And I want to pass on the client IP all the way to the `Service Backend`.

I have tried using the [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For), but this only works with the first proxy hop. That is, `Backend for SPA` is able to get the original client IP.

It is the processes of forwarding this same client IP via `Service Proxy` to `Service backend` that I am not sure how to handle. Using the same `X-Forwarded-For` will pass on `Backend for SPA` IP address to `Service Backend` instead of the `Clients IP`

What is the recommended way of handling this situation?

The thought I have is to update the code in `Backend for SPA` to take the clients IP it gets via `X-Forwarded-For`, and put it in a custom HTTP header which `Service Backend` can then retrieve.

Is this the recommended way? or there is more idiomatic way to handle this?